# Javascript funcionan despues de navegar NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

Hola estoy pasando un template de html a NextJS.
Cuando carga el sitio por primera vez, carga todo los js, despues de navegar hacia otra pagina. Y regresarme al Inicio, ya no me funciona el Slider, el boton de abrir menu etc

_document.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'


class MyDocument extends Document {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
        return { ...initialProps }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <Html>
                <Head>                   
                    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                    <link href="/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                </Head>
                <body data-template="template-basketball">

                    <div class="site-wrapper clearfix">
                        <div class="site-overlay"></div>
                        <Main />
                    </div>

                    <NextScript />
                    <script src="/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="/vendor/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="/js/core.js"></script>
                    <script src="/js/init.js"></script>
                </body>
            </Html>
        )   
    }
}

export default MyDocument
```

Answer (score 1):

Proba remplazando todo el html a un documento jsx o tsx y debería funcionar; los estilos usa modules css y los scripts transcribilos como funciones.
Estas usando un framework de react sin usar react, practicamente.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente el problema esté relacionado con que pretendes usar Next.JS como un servidor para alojar JS con jQuery.

Si quieres usar Next.JS debes utilizar React, ese será el problema.